# Dropping duplicate numbers only and only at the end of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I know how can I drop duplicates from a numpy array.
However, I ONLY & ONLY need to drop duplicates at the end of the numpy array by keeping one of them.
Please see my example below:

Example input is as follows:

```
105
106
106
107
108
109
109
109
109
```

Desired output:

```
105
106
106
107
108
109
```

Note that 106 is not dropped and I kept the last duplicate (109) without repetition.
Is there an elegant solution without using loops?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one vectorized way based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62312183/) -

```
In [168]: a
Out[168]: array([2, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9])

In [169]: a[:-(a[::-1]==a[-1]).argmin()+1]
Out[169]: array([2, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 9])
```

Comment: this solution keeps the type of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
l = [105,
     106,
     106,
     107,
     108,
     109,
     109,
     109,
     109]
l = [str(n) for n in l]
l = [int(n) for n in (' '.join(l).rstrip(" "+l[-1])+" "+l[-1]).split()]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[105,
 106,
 106,
 107,
 108,
 109]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from panda: pd.unique(list)

Comment: This does not work. Because this will drop all duplicates in the array.