# Finding number of duplicates only and only at the end of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates

I know how can I find the number of duplicates from a numpy array.
However, I  need to find the number of duplicates **only at the end** of the **numpy array**.
Please see my example below:

Example input is as follows:

```
1995
1996
1996
1997
1998
1999
1999
1999
```

Desired output:

```
3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) -

```
np.minimum.accumulate(a[::-1]==a[-1]).sum()
```

Sample run -

```
In [64]: a
Out[64]: array([2, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9])

In [73]: np.minimum.accumulate(a[::-1]==a[-1]).sum()
Out[73]: 5
```

---

Another with `argmin` -

```
In [88]: (a[::-1]==a[-1]).argmin()
Out[88]: 5
```

For a corner case, if all elements are same, we might need one extra step to check for `all` matches on `a[::-1]==a[-1]` and return `len(a)` in that case. Or if the count is `0`, which can't be the output, we will output `len(a)` instead.

Comment: Hey, why not just sum it like  np.sum( data == data[-1] ) , any specific advantage of np.minimum.accumulate ?

Comment: @PavanKumarPolavarapu Because we want to skip the intermediate elements that matches the last element if I understood OP's intent of `only at the end of the numpy array` correctly.

Comment: Umm, makes sense :)

Comment: @PavanKumarPolavarapu many thanks for your attention. **only at the end of the numpy array** was key for this question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows, however, I am sure that there is a more elegant solution in a line!

```
def get_numlastdups(my_nparray):
    numlastdups=0
    for i in range(2,len(my_nparray)):
        if my_nparray[-1]==my_nparray[-i]: numlastdups+=1
        else: break 
    return numlastdups
```

Comment: This will not work - since you don't break the loop on hitting a non-duplicate, **all** values equal to the last one (not just those in a streak) will be counted.

Comment: @Blotosmetek Actually it will work since i only consider the last element in the if section, but you've a point about the break. I added a break.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [1995,
1996,
1996,
1997,
1998,
1999,
1999,
1999]
s = 0
x = mylist[-1]
for i in mylist:
   if i == x: s+= 1
print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code will return the correct results however there should be break when the loop encounter a non-duplicate.